# Extract column from DataTable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

Is there a way to extract all items from a single column in a DataTable instead of using a For Each loop?

Eg, the following builds a List of KeyValuePair from each Row in a single column of a DataTable

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> extract = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
foreach (DataRow item in _dataTableTest.Rows)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, double> selection = (KeyValuePair<string, double>)item["Selection"];
    extract.Add(selection);
}
```

Is there a better way and/or quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Linq-To-DataTable`

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> extract = _dataTableTest.AsEnumerable()
          .Select(r => r.Field<KeyValuePair<string, double>>("Selection"))
          .ToList();
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq;` and that this is not "quicker" in terms of performance. It also uses loops internally.